# How to prevent Android Studio recompile all C++ code everytime build?

Tags: c++, android-studio, android-ndk

There is a very strange problem. Everytime I build apk using Android Studio, it recompile all C++ code, but I haven't change any C++ code and the Android.mk file. It waste a lot of time!!! Who could give me some advices?

Comment: First, check that you have the latest Android Studio 2.3.3 and your gradle plugin and build tools are up to date. Does your externalNativeBuild block use cmake or ndk-build?

Comment: Did you find a solution?